# Where is this New York City Broadway location from Fall 1958?

Tags: new-york-city, photo-identification, 1950s

I'm trying to identify the location of this photograph from the Fall of 1958 in New York City.  One store in photo says Broadway Book Store, so I assume this is Broadway.

[image]

It might be Broadway and West 47th Street near times square due to what I [found here](https://ephemeralnewyork.wordpress.com/tag/times-square/) which shows a 1975 photo which includes a Florsheim shoes and a movie theatre.  However, the Google street view of today looks nothing like this.

Perhaps this is the Macy's Day Parade from Thanksgiving 1958?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this is on Broadway on the W 42nd St block.

Changed a lot since this photo taken but on Google Streetview you can see the old building (now [Knickerbocker Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Knickerbocker_Hotel_(Manhattan))) on the right is still standing, quite distinctive brickwork.

[image]

Source: [Google Streetview](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7560928,-73.9863132,3a,75y,139.82h,101.7t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipPyIP1-ygM3F_xHUCLmJn3ymGV2RYSk-27RbYzb!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPyIP1-ygM3F_xHUCLmJn3ymGV2RYSk-27RbYzb%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya92.798996-ro-0-fo100!7i7168!8i3584)

Found this by checking an old Manhattan directory for Broadway Bookshop and Florsheim - the closest year I could find on a quick search was this [1946 directory](http://www.donslist.net/PGHLookups/cgi-bin/HandOff-1_0.cgi?Manhattan1946%20Manhattan1946%200000SP), but that was good enough. Then just going over to our friend Google streetview…

Agree that the Macy's Thanksgiving Day Parade seems logical for the event.